# Question related to Inverse relation shadow variable of Optaplanner?

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

I have a planning entity called **TaskAssignment** that has two genuine planning variables namely : *TaskStartTime* and *AssignedCrewMember*. I have another planning entity called **CrewMember** that contains only an inverse relation shadow variable : *TaskAssignmentList* that contains the list of **TaskAssignment** entities that are assigned this particular **CrewMember**. I currently have this inverse relation shadow variable referenced to the *AssignedCrewMember* planning variable in the **TaskAssignment** planning entity.

My question is : Are the entities in *TaskAssignmentList* just copies of the original entities ? Or Does the entity get updated even if only the *TaskStartTime* variable is changed by Optaplanner. I am asking this because the source variable of this Inverse Relation shadow variable is only *AssignedCrewMember*. Please help me understand this.